# How to implement partial wakeLock correctly?

Tags: java, android, android-wake-lock

I have found ways to implement it as follows...

code:

```
public class main extends AppCompatActivity implements View.OnClickListener{

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_lvl_1);
    getWindow().addFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);
    PowerManager pm = (PowerManager) getSystemService(Context.POWER_SERVICE);
    PowerManager.WakeLock wl = pm.newWakeLock(PowerManager.PARTIAL_WAKE_LOCK, "AppName: tag");
    wl.acquire();
    wl.release();
}
```

And then I have also added the permission code for wake lock in manifest. However, it does not work properly, as the screen goes off, when I reopen the screen again, my app closes and some random error occurs.(the error is not related to wakelock, but because of the presence of partial wakelock codes that I have added). Guys, pls help me out. I have been stuck in this issue for almost a week. Thanks in advance, guys.

Comment: why are you releasing it? from docs: "... CPU will be kept on until all partial wake locks have been released."

Answer (score 0):

I strongly recommend you to read this Android Documentation on Doze Mode [Keep the device awake](https://developer.android.com/training/scheduling/wakelock#cpu)

Avoid using Wake Locks if you want to keep the screen on.

If you want to keep the screen on in your Activity use this tag `window.addFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_KEEP_SCREEN_ON)` in you onCreate

 Or 
You can achieve the same behavior by XML Tag.
**android:keepScreenOn="true"**

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:keepScreenOn="true">
    ...
</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for the answer but that is not what I want. The thing that I want to achieve is that I allow the screen to turn off. Then, when I turn on the screen again, the app remains open. But for now, it exits after screen goes off.

Comment: @Newbie can you please provide the error you're getting?